# Use node bins without installing the package globally

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface, package.json

I created an npm package that is used both as a library, but also as a CLI. In my package.json, therefore, exists something like this:

```
"bin": {
  "mycommand": "<somescript>"
}
```

If I install the package globally using "npm i -g" I can use the command in the terminal, by typing:

```
mycommand <someargs>
```

As the package also contains elements that should be imported by other projects, the package should be installed locally to the respective superior project:

```
npm i mypackage
```

When I do this, the commands of the bin-section of the package.json aren't working. But there seem to be npm packages that support this also for local dependencies (although I can't imagine how (regarding the PATH-Variable etc.))

Is there a way how I can achieve what I want, or will I have to split the package into a library module, a CLI-module and a common-module, where the CLI-package has to be installed globally?

Comment: Install every package locally as devdependency => `npm i -D some-package`. Now, if you want to use it, define an entry in `scripts` section calling the command. Then your package manager checks for the command in your prject `node_modules` and after in your gloabally installed `node_modules`.

Do `npm i -my-package` then define an entry in `scripts` as `"custom-script": "my-package -my-param"` and call it from command line. For example with npm: `npm run custom-script`

Comment: Thank you! It did indead work. I didn't know that the commands used in NPM scripts are automatically resolved by NPM 

Comment: good ^^        Enjoy your day.